# Android resource filenames in unicode breaks stuff?

Tags: android, eclipse, unicode

I'm porting an app with lots of resource files using filenames of this kind:

- game_sound_phrase_コンパス.mp3
- game_sound_phrase_シンバル.mp3

I get the feeling that something in Android and/or Eclipse breaks with this.

- game_sound_phrase_„ÅÑ„Åã„Åù„ÅÜ„ÇÅ„Çì01.mp3: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.
- game_sound_phrase_„ÅÑ„Åã„Åù„ÅÜ„ÇÅ„Çì01.mp3: error: Invalid filename.  Unable to add.

I have a lot of these files. Must I rename them??

Btw these files are put in raw/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource files in Eclipse are currently required to have filenames containing only `(a-z0-9-_)`: lowercase a-z, 0-9, dashes, and underscores. This is a known limitation and has been around for a while, so you will need to rename your files.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if your problem is solved, or post back if you're still having problems.